# SQL Server : split records pointing to a unique varbinary value

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an interesting problem for the smart people out there.
I have an external application I cannot modify writing pictures into a SQL Server table. The pictures are often non-unique, but linked to unique rows in other tables.

The table `MyPictures` looks like this (simplified):

```
Unique (ID)     FileName (Varchar)     Picture (Varbinary)  
----------------------------------------------------------
xxx-xx-xxx1     MyPicture              0x66666666  
xxx-xx-xxx2     MyPicture              0x66666666  
xxx-xx-xxx3     MyPicture              0x66666666
```

This causes the same data to be stored over and over again, blowing up my database (85% of my DB is just this table).

Is there something on a SQL level I can do to only store the data once if filename & picture already exists in my table?

Comment: store an ID to a pictures table instead of storing the binary field where it can be duplicated?

Comment: How do you insert to this table? through an application?. One record at a time?

Comment: If you can't change the application that inserts and retrieves these pictures there is little you can do. You could possibly get tricky with some instead of triggers and views that would have the name of the current table. This requires quite a bit of effort to make sure you get it all correct.

Comment: Hi Ala, it is indeed one record at a time

What do you mean Beth?

Comment: It sounds like that you want is not different than any other type of data. You can create a job to find min or max id in the picture table and refer to it in the foreign table and delete all other rows.

Comment: It looks to me like the database is denormalized either by design or accident. I think what @Beth is saying is that a better way to do this might be to have an "ID" table and a "Picture" table where there is a 1 to many relationship between ID and Picture. Unfortunately, there isn't much you can do to fix this without modifying either the code or the stored procedures doing the insert.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to treat the current destination table as a 'staging' table, so allow all the rows the upstream process wants to write to it, but then have a second process that copies only distinct rows to the table(s) you're using on the SQL side and then deletes the rows from the table with the duplicates to reclaim your space.

Comment: Thanks for the time of looking at this. The strudgle for me is that the application both reads and writes to the same table. So I would need to build something which 'tricks' the application as to see it as one table.

Comment: so all you need to do is delete duplicate values in the picture column?  Or are any of the other columns meaningful to the other processes?